# SWXMLHash compact root element

Tags: xml, swift, parsing, root, swxmlhash

I have a question I hope will be quick. I am parsing XML returned by eBay’s API using SWXMLHash for Swift. Some of the returns get quite verbose.

such as:

```
 xml["findCompletedItemsResponse"][“searchResults"][“item”]...[“sellerID"].element?.text
```

How would I go about compacting this to say:

```
xml[rootVar][“item”]...[“sellerID"].element?.text
```

is there a way to specify this in this instantiation? I have tried (which obviously did not work):

```
let xml = SWXMLHash.config { 
    config in
    config.shouldProcessLazily  = true
    config.shouldProcessNamespaces  = true
    rootElementName = "findCompletedItemsResponse"
}.parse(response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like:

```
let rootXml = xml["findCompletedItemsResponse"]["searchResults"]
// ...
let sellerID = rootXml["item"]...["sellerID"].element?.text
```

Each indexed level can be saved off into a variable - it is just an instance of `XMLIndexer` that has been indexed down a certain level.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep. Thank you! New to XML with Swift and got too focused on the forest I did not see the obvious tree. Your SWXMLHash is very well created. Thank you for sharing not only this wonderful tool but also your support as well!